# Differential cross section $d\sigma/dp^{\gamma}_{T}$?

Tags: particle-physics, phase-space, scattering-cross-section, tevatron

Why we care about $d\sigma/dp^{\gamma}_{T}$? What the physical meaning of it?
Why not plot $\sigma$ follow $p^{\gamma}_{T}$?. As in this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The differential cross section:
$$
\frac{\text{d}\sigma(p\bar p \to \gamma\cdots)}{\text{d} p_T^\gamma}
$$ 
is proportional to a probability density function (pdf) for the transverse momentum of the photon $p_T^\gamma$. In fact, if a photon is produced in the above process, the pdf for its transverse momentum would be
$$
p(p_T^\gamma) = \frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{\text{d}\sigma(p\bar p \to \gamma\cdots)}{\text{d} p_T^\gamma}
$$
This tells us how much $P_T$ the photon is likely to have.

This might be useful if, for example, we want to discriminate a signal from a background with the $p_T$ variable, or compare predictions with observations for the distribution of the photon's $p_T$.
Note that $\sigma$ isn't a function of $p_T$ (or of the momentum of any of the final state products) because we integrate over the phase space to find the cross section,
$$
\sigma = \frac{1}{2I} \int |M|^2 \text{d}^n\Phi.
$$
where $\text{d}^n\Phi$ is the $n$-body phase-space of the $n$ particles produced.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please provide me related paper,book of this. I wanna have more paper, book about $p(p^{\gamma}_{T})=\dfrac{1}{\sigma}\dfrac{d\sigma(p\bar{p}\rightarrow\gamma ...)}{dp^{\gamma}_{T}}$